# Protect server ports from being used for attacks

Tags: windows, security, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm a programmer and I just know some basic & web development related thing like managing dns, adding websites to iis &...

I have had two different servers and both of them was shut down because my server was used for launching attacks on other servers.

I have always used very strong passwords 
I always have the windows firewall on
Just opened the ports that are used for mail, sql server & ftp

But still have problems with server security. I want to know

**Where to start**

**What should I read or search about**

**Can free antivirus products help me with this?** (Becuase right now I don't have the budget to buy expensive softwares)

These are the sample attack reports that last time I had received from the data center (which I didn't understood a bit):

```
2016-04-06 18:00:14.448433 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 109, id 32364, offset 0, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500) 148.251.78.182.53 > 66.150.188.x.53233: 17222| 247/0/1 amplists.com. A 192.168.1.150, amplists.com.[|domain]
x0000: 4500 05dc 7e6c 2000 6d11 c6ba 94fb 4eb6 E...~l..m.....N.
x0010: 4296 bca2 0035 cff1 0fa1 8245 4346 8380 B....5.....ECF..
x0020: 0001 00f7 0000 0001 0861 6d70 6c69 7374 .........amplist
x0030: 7303 636f 6d00 00ff 0001 c00c 0001 0001 s.com...........
x0040: 0000 2527 0004 c0a8 0196 c00c 0001 0001 ..%'............
x0050: 0000 ..

2016-04-06 18:00:14.448501 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 109, id 32365, offset 0, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500) 148.251.78.182.53 > 66.150.188.x.53233: 17222| 247/0/1 amplists.com. A 192.168.1.150, amplists.com.[|domain]
x0000: 4500 05dc 7e6d 2000 6d11 c6b9 94fb 4eb6 E...~m..m.....N.
x0010: 4296 bca2 0035 cff1 0fa1 8245 4346 8380 B....5.....ECF..
x0020: 0001 00f7 0000 0001 0861 6d70 6c69 7374 .........amplist
x0030: 7303 636f 6d00 00ff 0001 c00c 0001 0001 s.com...........
x0040: 0000 2527 0004 c0a8 0196 c00c 0001 0001 ..%'............
x0050: 0000 ..

2016-04-06 18:00:14.448503 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 109, id 32366, offset 0, flags [+], proto UDP (17), length 1500) 148.251.78.182.53 > 66.150.188.x.53233: 17222| 247/0/1 amplists.com. A 192.168.1.150, amplists.com.[|domain]
x0000: 4500 05dc 7e6e 2000 6d11 c6b8 94fb 4eb6 E...~n..m.....N.
x0010: 4296 bca2 0035 cff1 0fa1 8245 4346 8380 B....5.....ECF..
x0020: 0001 00f7 0000 0001 0861 6d70 6c69 7374 .........amplist
x0030: 7303 636f 6d00 00ff 0001 c00c 0001 0001 s.com...........
x0040: 0000 2527 0004 c0a8 0196 c00c 0001 0001 ..%'............
x0050: 0000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular signature means that you have a misconfigured DNS server running. It allows anyone to run [DNS Amplification Attack](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_Amplification_Attack) from your host. It doesn't matter how strong is your password in that case. [Please follow this guide](https://serverfault.com/questions/525730/dns-amplification-attack) to configure your server correctly (or just disable DNS completely if you don't need it)...

As for antivirus, I don't think that it should really be an addition to server security, unless you use it for running client terminals...